# Checking if 2 strings are equivalent with backslash added\removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a network path string:

```
\\earth\config\Movie\PW
```

I need to compare, if its value has changed. Value will be changed with it gets modified to:

```
\\earth\config\Movie\JR\PW\Foo
```

or

```
\\bar\earth\config\Movie\PW
```

i.e when the above path changes in reality. But it will not be changed, if some backslashes are added in between,before or after the string. Like, the original path is equivalent to:

```
\\earth\config\Movie\PW\
```

or

```
\\earth\config\Movie\\\PW
```

or

```
\\earth\\\\config\Movie\PW
```

What is the best and optimal way to compare these strings, to check if they are equivalent (even after adding backslash at the end/between/before the string)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all forward slashes by space and then compare the strings

```
str1.replace(/\\+/g, '') === str2.replace(/\\+/g, '')
```

```js
var isEqual = "\\earth\config\Movie\PW\\".replace(/\\+/g, '').trim() === "\\earth\config\Movie\\\PW".replace(/\\+/g, '').trim();
// Also use trim to remove the leading and trailing spaces
document.write(isEqual);
```

Comment: If folder name is "Movie PW" or "MoviePW" then it works or not?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Only forward slashes are removed, spaces are not, so if other string does not contain space between the two words, it should not work

Answer (score 0):

if you have to do it lots of times might want to try this:

```js
var one ='\\earth\config\Movie\\\PW';
var two='\\earth\\\\config\Movie\PW';

String.prototype.comparePath = function(b){
 return this.split(/\\+/).join('') === b.split(/\\+/).join('');

};

console.log( one.comparePath(two) )
```

Comment: If folder name is "Movie PW" or "MoviePW" then it works or not?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi It works comparing strings with forward slashes

Comment: getting true for this. This is not correct. "MoviePW" is a single Folder Name. "Movie\PW" are two different then also getting true.